# use htaccess to redirect any desktop users to holding page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, user-agent

I have a mobile web-app which isn't desktop ready just yet, and I don't want users to be able to view the desktop version of the app just yet. Is it possible to catch any requests from desktop browsers and redirect to a holding page, or possibly even to a tablet version of the site by appending the User Agent info to the URL? A basic attempt at this is as follows, and doesn't work...

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ holding.jpg [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `RewriteRule`'s regex so that it'll match *anything*:

```
RewriteRule .* holding.jpg [L,R]
```